# solr integrate highlighting data within main search results

Tags: solr, highlight

I am using highlighting feature in solr 8.3 with default method.  With current behaviour, main search results and highlighted results are shown in different blocks. Is there a way we can implemented highlighting within the search main results, without having to return extra block for highlighting?

I believe that due to performance factor(like default limit values for hl.maxAnalyzedChars, hl.snippets, hl.fragsize) that highlight is returned as separate component. But, if someone has written custom component to integrate both, please share the steps. Also, please share the performance of it.

[solr-results-with-highlights](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pau8B.png)

Comment: How do you want to integrate highlighting within the results? Since highlighting doesn't really return all the content (or the original content), presenting it as such in the main document information can lead to problems where tools depend on the actual stored text being returned.

Comment: I wish to integrate the hightlighting filed data with main results in another field(if the highlighting is present). We can control highlighting content with fragsize.